# Canon 60d pc sync adapter

Tags: canon, canon-60d

60d does not have pc sync. Is there some adapters that I can use to work strobs with my camera ? Maybe some hot shoe adapter ?
I know about wireless adapters which can do the job, ofcourse, but they are about 40 eur in my country, so I thought some pc sync can maybe be cheaper and do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can get a hotshoe adaptor with a PC sync port:

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/89979-REG/Hama_HA_6951_Hot_Shoe_Adapter_1.html

Cheap versions are also available from eBay.

If you are using a ancient flashgun which is likely to have a trigger voltage in excess of 5V then I would recommend using a Wien SafeSync to protect the camera electronics:

http://www.weinproducts.com/safesyncs.htm